# Consider a sequence u where u is defined as follows:

Tags: javascript

Consider a sequence u where u is defined as follows:

The number `u(0) = 1` is the first one in `u`.
For each `x` in `u`, then `y = 2 * x + 1` and `z = 3 * x + 1` must be in u too.

There are no other numbers in u.
Ex: `u = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]`

1 gives 3 and 4, then 3 gives 7 and 10, 4 gives 9 and 13, then 7 gives 15 and 22 and so on...

Task:

Given parameter `n` the function `dbl_linear` (or `dblLinear`...) returns the element `u(n)` of the ordered (with <=) sequence `u`.

Example:

`dbl_linear(10)` should return `22`

I have tried:

```
function dblLinear(n) {
  if(n === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if(n % 2 === 0) {
    return dblLinear(n-1) * 3 + 1;
  } else {
    return dblLinear(n-1) * 2 + 1;
  }
}
```

this is the origin link in codeWars:
can't thought the test. help --> [link](http://www.codewars.com/kata/5672682212c8ecf83e000050/train/javascript)

Comment: please add your question.

Comment: What do you want? you want to "know if your number is part of your u()"?

Comment: @NinaScholz Problem has been perfect

Comment: @Julo0sS calculate the u[n]

Comment: How can your dbl_linear(10) return 22? oO Can't get it...

Comment: Btw you can have some double records. y == z in this case :  (2*3)+1 == (3*2)+1 ...

Comment: @Julo0sS help --> [link](http://www.codewars.com/kata/5672682212c8ecf83e000050/train/javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution features an array for every calculated values until the wanted element is calculated.

> ```
>  u   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13         element
>  v   1   3   4   7   9  10  13  15  19  21  22  27  28  31         value
>  0   1                                                             1
>  1       3                                                         1 * 2 + 1
>  1           4                                                     1 * 3 + 1
>  3               7                                                 3 * 2 + 1
>  3                      10                                         3 * 3 + 1
>  4                   9                                             4 * 2 + 1
>  4                          13                                     4 * 3 + 1
>  7                              15                                 7 * 2 + 1
>  7                                          22                     7 * 3 + 1
>  9                                   19                            9 * 2 + 1
>  9                                                  28             9 * 3 + 1
> 10                                      21                        10 * 2 + 1 
> 10                                                       31       10 * 3 + 1
> ```

```js
var array = [1],
    i = 0;

function add(v) {
    array.some(function (a, i) {
        if (a >= v) {
            a > v && array.splice(i, 0, v);
            return true;
        }
    }) || array.push(v);
}

while (i < 10) {
    add(array[i] * 2 + 1);
    add(array[i] * 3 + 1);
    i++;
}

document.write('u(10): ' + array[10]);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: can't thought the test. help --> [link](http://www.codewars.com/kata/5672682212c8ecf83e000050/train/javascript)

Comment: the link requires a login, i do not have one. please use another host. please write what the problem is.